# Python return formated string according to a value in dictionary

Tags: python, string-formatting

In Python, I have a script which receives input from external sources with the name of 1 or more variables, it then looks for the current values on a PLC and returns them to the client.

On the script I define all possible variables and the required format and unit to display to client.

```
given_variable = "temp1"  #Client needs current value of temp1
vars_format = {
    "temp1":["%0.1f","C"],
    "press1":["%0.2f","bar"],
    "temp2":["%d","K"],
    "distance":["%0.3f","km"],
    "switch":["%d",""]
}

# Logic for finding current plc_value of given_variable
# plc_value is a string that looks like a real number
# ("3.14159"), an integer "3" or a string "Running"

return "%s %s" % ( plc_value, vars_format[ given_variable ][1] )
```

How to dynamically (according to dictionary) return the plc_value in the required format?
In the example, how to get "23.4 C" instead of "23.39999 C" for "temp1" or "45.21 bar" instead of "42.21248 bar" for "press1"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, apply your value to what `vars_format` returns:

```
return "%s %s" % (vars_format[given_variable][0] % plc_value, vars_format[given_variable][1])
```

But that's ugly as hell. Why don't you just define everything as a nice source string that you can swap based on the `given_variable`:

```
vars_format = {
    "temp1": "%0.1f C",
    "press1":"%0.2f bar",
    "temp2": "%d K",
    "distance": "%0.3f km",
    "switch": "%d"
}

return vars_format[given_variable] % plc_value
```

Or even better, use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for more flexibility and more modern string substitution options.

Comment: I changed my vars to "nice source string".. Thanks!